# Azure PHP SDK: get the asset by asset name

Tags: php, azure, sdk, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to get the asset details using asset name with Azure PHP sdk. I can get all the asset list, but it's loading first 1000 assets only.

```
getAssetList();
```

I can get single asset details using asset id.

```
getAsset($asset);
```

But in my case, I don't have asset id with me. I just have asset name alone. Now how do I get the asset details using this?

EDIT:

I got some help from Azure support saying that, we can use $skip parameter for pagination. I got code snippet in c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < _context.Assets.Count(); i += 1000 )
{
    var assets = _context.Assets.Skip(i);
    foreach (IAsset objIAsset in assets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(objIAsset.Name.ToString());
    }
}
```

How can I use this param in PHP SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that Azure SDK for PHP don't support skip method. However, I used the fiddler to monitor C# skip method and got the URL like this:

```
https://***-hs.cloudapp.net/api/Assets()?$skip=1000
```

So I think we can bulid up the request path like above in our PHP project and we can modify the `getAssetList` method in "`MediaServicesRestProxy`" file.

I add a function named "`getAssetListBySkip($number)`" into "`MediaServicesRestProxy`" class, the code like this:

```
/**
 * Get asset list using skip number
 * 
 * */
public function getAssetListBySkip($number)
{
    $propertyList = $this->_getEntityList("Assets()?".'$skip='.$number);
    $result       = array();

    foreach ($propertyList as $properties) {
        $result[] = Asset::createFromOptions($properties);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

We can call this method like this:

```
$mediaServiceProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createMediaServicesService(
        new MediaServicesSettings("**","**/**="));
$result=$mediaServiceProxy->getAssetListBySkip(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Azure Media services supports filtering by name. You can construct web request to be like

```
/api/assets()?$filter=Name%20eq%20'Your Name'&$top=1
```

You can also filter by other properties

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried REST API that are used when creating, processing, managing, and delivering Assets. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974277.aspx#list_an_asset but I do think we can list asset via a name directly since id is an unique indentifier of [asset entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh974277.aspx#asset_entity_properties). [PHP Azure SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/84bac84abc57dccd94603a0fcac3277aa47c3257/WindowsAzure/MediaServices/MediaServicesRestProxy.php) leverages assetId to get an Asset as well:

```
 public function getAsset($asset) 
     { 
         $assetId = Utilities::getEntityId( 
           $asset, 
             'WindowsAzure\MediaServices\Models\Asset' 
        ); 

         return Asset::createFromOptions($this->_getEntity("Assets('{$assetId}')")); 
     }
```

> But in my case, I don't have asset id with me. I just have asset name
>   alone. Now how do I get the asset details using this?

Here are some test function code snippets for your reference:

```
public function testListAllAssets(){ 
           // Setup 
         $asset1 = new Asset(Asset::OPTIONS_NONE); 
         $asset1->setName(TestResources::MEDIA_SERVICES_ASSET_NAME . $this->createSuffix()); 

         $asset2 = new Asset(Asset::OPTIONS_NONE); 
         $asset2->setName(TestResources::MEDIA_SERVICES_ASSET_NAME . $this->createSuffix()); 

         // Test 
         $asset1 = $this->createAsset($asset1); 
         $asset2 = $this->createAsset($asset2); 
         $result = $this->restProxy->getAssetList(); 

         // Assert 
         $this->assertCount(2, $result); 
         $names = array( 
             $result[0]->getName(), 
             $result[1]->getName() 
         ); 
         $id = array( 
                 $result[0]->getId(), 
                 $result[1]->getId() 
         ); 
         $this->assertContains($asset1->getName(), $names); 
         $this->assertContains($asset2->getName(), $names); 

         $this->assertContains($asset1->getId(), $id); 
         $this->assertContains($asset2->getId(), $id); 
     } 

 public function testGetAnAssetReference(){ 

         // Setup 
         $assetName = TestResources::MEDIA_SERVICES_ASSET_NAME . $this->createSuffix(); 
         $asset = new Asset(Asset::OPTIONS_NONE); 
         $asset->setName($assetName); 
         $asset = $this->createAsset($asset); 

         // Test 
         $result = $this->restProxy->getAsset($asset); 

         // Assert 
         $this->assertEquals($asset->getId(), $result->getId()); 
         $this->assertEquals($asset->getName(), $result->getName()); 
     }
```

From: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/tests/functional/WindowsAzure/MediaServices/MediaServicesFunctionalTest.php

Comment: I tried this method, but when i try to create new asset with same name new container is created. in this case i can't obtain the already created containers SAS url's.

Comment: Is this possible to provide a code snippet in your post to let us reproduce your issue [create new asset with same name new container is created.] conveniently? For now, I could not fully understand your root cause.

Answer (score 0):

According to my testing, it seems that we can’t use Asset’s name to get the information of asset in Media Service.

```
$mediaServiceProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createMediaServicesService(
              new MediaServicesSettings("**","******"));
$asset = new Asset(Asset::OPTIONS_NONE);
$asset->setName('For-Test-wmv-Source');
//$asset don't have the value of id,
// unless execute ‘createAsset($asset)’, "$asset1" will be set the ID 
$asset1 =$mediaServiceProxy->createAsset($asset);
$result2=$mediaServiceProxy->getAsset($asset1);
```

PHP SDK support the method named “getAsset($asset)”. Actually,  the method get the Asset information by Asset id, just like the `Aka's reference code`.And Azure REST API don’t support the method queried by Asset’s name.
Please refer to the [official document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974277.aspx).

Alternative approach is that you can store your assets information (such as Id,URl,name and ect.) into `Azure table storage` when you upload them into media service. If you want to use it, you can fetch and filter the data of Asset’s name you wants from `table storage`.

Comment: Yes I can store it for my future use. But unfortunately I missed them to store. So now I have more than 2000 assets. Is there any other work around to get this done?

Comment: As i mentioned in my question EDIT, i got some help from Azure support to use $skip for paging. But i couldn't find any PHP documentation for this.